# How to put a checkbox on each row in a Gridview and link to a submit button in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to put a checkbox on each row in a GridView, and also link that GridView with a submit button, like this image:
[image]

The objective is for each checked and unchecked row do an Insert on a certain table from the database. I need help, please.

This the code for the GridView I have for now:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'rutAlumno',
            'nombreAlumno',
            'apellidoAlumno',
            'cursoAlumno',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a CheckboxColumn to the yii\grid\GridView, add it to the columns configuration as follows

```
 ['class' => CheckboxColumn::className()],
```

Users may click on the checkboxes to select rows of the grid. The selected rows may be obtained by calling the following JavaScript code:

```
var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
// keys is an array consisting of the keys associated with the selected rows
```

For more [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        'rutAlumno',
        'nombreAlumno',
        'apellidoAlumno',
        'cursoAlumno',

        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

It will generate checkboxes for each row. Now right the js script

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(e){
    var selectedKeys = $('#your-grid-id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
     /* your code */ });
```